# INSERT part of sql with UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't work, updating does work

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, duplicates

First off, forgive me the unsafe code, I will work on that later on.
For now this problem:

I have a page with a form to which a user can add fields and modify existing fields.

I sent the form and when the input is new I also create an empty hidden input field for the primary key column that's empty to add a new row to db. Only this row is not being created. When user modifies existing row it does work. So the update on duplicate key part works, but the Insert part for a new field does not work.

I already used print_r to check what the variables look like and indeed like I wanted for a new field footNoteID is empty and footNoteNL contains whatever user entered, and for a modified field footNoteID has the old primary key value and whatever was modified. So that looks alright.

Yet the Insert part for a new field does not work.

This is the code on the php page that processes the form:

```
// two posted arrays from a form with multiple input fields

$footNoteNL = $_POST['footNoteNL'];
$footNoteID = $_POST['checkfootNoteID'];

// looping through the arrays

for($j=0, $count = count($footNoteNL); $j<$count; $j++) {

$footNoteNLThis  = $footNoteNL[$j];
$footNoteIDThis =  $footNoteID[$j];

    
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO footnotes (footNoteID, albumID, addedDate, footNoteNL, footNoteEN) VALUES ('".$footNoteIDThis."', '92', '".$datum."' , '".$footNoteNLThis."', 0)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE footNoteNL = '".$footNoteNLThis."'";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
```

This is the form on the HTML side, and the jquery that adds the input and hidden field. This part works. I use brackets on the form field to create a posted array. Like said, when checking what gets posted it seems ok.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addButton').on('click', function () {
        $(".footNoteContainer").prepend("<div><input type='hidden' name='checkfootNoteID[]' value=''><TEXTAREA NAME='footNoteNL[]'></TEXTAREA>
// and so on
```

The part of the form this gets prepended to:

```
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM footnotes WHERE albumID = '.$album_id.' ORDER BY addedDate ASC') as $row ) {

<TEXTAREA NAME='footNoteNL[]'>".stripslashes($row['footNoteNL'])."</TEXTAREA>
<input type=\"hidden\" NAME=\"checkfootNoteID[]\" VALUE=\"".stripslashes($row['footNoteID'])."\">

// and so on, just to show that here the field are non empty since they get pulled form db
```

and here is what a check looks like when adding a new field, and modifying an existing ones: "_newly added field value 9092_old input value"

So before the underscore of the newly created field, there is no value for $footNoteIDThis , which makes me expect a new row gets added to db. For the modified field there is the old key "9292" so that\s a duplicate and indeed that one gets updated ...

this is dump form db:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


--
-- Table structure for table `footnotes`
--

CREATE TABLE `footnotes` (
  `footNoteID` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `albumID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `addedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `footNoteNL` text NOT NULL,
  `footNoteEN` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Indexes for table `footnotes`
--
ALTER TABLE `footnotes`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`footNoteID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `footnotes`
--
```

Sorry for all the info, hopefully it makes sense, sorry for cumbersome method, but I really don't see why this doesn't work, although I suspect the problem lies in the db table settings or structure?

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL `INSERT INTO footnotes...` only in the DB? Does it work?

Comment: well, I did not. Now I did and got an error:  #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column `authorless_infoauthorless_db`.`footnotes`.`footNoteID` at row 1. So i guess the posted value for primary key field when set to default can't have quotes?

Comment: it seems to work now, when I unquote single quotes the value intended for the primary key field. so '".$footNoteIDThis."' becomes ".$footNoteIDThis.". and then set the empty field to default instead of leaving empty... does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I think you didn't understand me well. I mean only run the `SQL` in your DB server without any php or js. I just want you to make sure the SQL works first.

Comment: yes that\s what I did, and then the db yielded that error "Incorrect integer value: ''" for column with primary key, so I removed the quotes that would be around the default value and now it works

Comment: What is the `SQL` you tried? You should try the same `SQL` twice with the same new primary key. 
First, you should insert one record. Second, change the SQL with different value but same key should update the records only.